# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null. Using two Javascript functions in the same page

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror

I have two JavaScript functions that I'm trying to implement but they appear to be clashing with each other.

One function called "showPage" displays/blocks selected pages when that page's button is clicked. Like this.

```
 function showPage(page) {
        document.querySelectorAll('tbody').forEach(tbody => {tbody.style.display = 'none';})

        document.querySelector(`#${page}`).style.display = 'table-row-group'; ---(This line in error message)
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(button => {
            button.onclick = function() {
                showPage(this.dataset.page); ---(This line in error message)
            }           
        });
    });
```

Here is one example of a button targeted by showPage, and one example of a page it will either display or block.

```
<button class="posbutton" data-page="page1">QB</button>


<tbody id="page1">
               
         {% for q in QBpage %}
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">
                      
                </th>
                    
                <td><h6>{{ q.player_name }}</h6></td>
                <td><button> class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" onclick="myFunction('{{ player_data.player_name }} {{ player_data.position }}')">Add</button></td>
                <td><h6> {{ q.team }} </h6></td>
                <td><h6> {{ q.position }}  </h6></td>
                <td><h6>{{ q.points }}</h6></td>
                </tr>
                  
         {% endfor %}
</tbody>
               <!--several more pages like the above-->
```

There are 5 pages in total that can be toggled. When a page is toggled to display, on the page there is a button that is linked to another JavaScript function called myFunction. This function submits text in the `<td>` element to a form field. Here's myFunction.

```
function myFunction(txt) {
        var myTxt = txt;
    
        
        if (txt.includes('QB')) {
            document.getElementById("QB_name").value = myTxt;
        }

        else if (txt.includes('RB')) {
            document.getElementById("RB_name").value = myTxt;
        }

        else if (txt.includes('WR')) {
            document.getElementById("WR_name").value = myTxt;
        }

        else if (txt.includes('TE')) {
            document.getElementById("TE_name").value = myTxt;
        }

        else if (txt.includes('K')) {
            document.getElementById("K_name").value = myTxt;
        }
        
    }
```

However, when I load a page and then click a button to submit the data in the row, this onclick causes the entire page to disappear. The console error message points to the line in showPage `showPage(this.dataset.page);` and I think the problem is because showPage is targeting all buttons with the line `document.querySelectorAll('button')` Clicking on a button to submit data using myFunction is actually calling showPage because showPage is targeting all the button elements on the page. So, how do I stop these two functions from clashing? This is where my knowledge runs out because I'm pretty new to JavaScript. I think I can see why it's not working, but I've no idea how to develop an alternative. Thanks in advance if you do read over this.

Comment: You speak of an error. What is the error message?

Comment: @trincot main2.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null    However, experimenting with the positioning of the script doesn't change anything.

Comment: With `document.querySelectorAll('button')` one does target any `<button/>` which means **also the ones that do not provide** a `[data-page]` attribute like the ones within the `<table/>`. If such a button gets clicked `this.dataset.page` will pass the `undefined` value to the `showPage` function which then does fail for this query part ... `document.querySelector(`#${page}`).style.display`.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Thanks. That sounds logical. I'm still thinking of a way for `this.dataset.page` to pass the correct value.

Comment: I would change your question. "Clashing functions" is not a thing in JavaScript. Focus on the error message.

Comment: @trincot this particular error message is slightly misleading. It's passing null because the wrong buttons are being targeted.

Comment: I know. But "clashing functions" is much more misleading. The error is correctly highlighting what the run time error is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `document.querySelectorAll('button')` one does target any `<button/>` which means **also the ones that do not provide** a `[data-page]` attribute like the ones within the `<tbody/>`.

If such a button gets clicked `this.dataset.page` will pass the `undefined` value to the `showPage` function which then does fail at accessing `.style.display` for the query result of ``` document.querySelector(``#${page}``) ```.

In order to initialize the event handling correctly at first place one might try changing the code accordingly by targeting `[data-page]` buttons only ...

```
function handleShowPage(evt) {
  // showPage(this.dataset.page);
  showPage(evt.currentTarget.dataset.page);
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document
    .querySelectorAll('button[data-page]')
    .forEach(button =>
      button.addEventListener('click', handleShowPage)
    );
});
```

***Edit***

> *However, when I load a page and then click a button to submit the data in the row, this onclick causes the entire page to disappear.*

Any button which does not specifically state its type via its `[type]` attribute will trigger the submit of its form by which it is contained.

Thus, in order to prevent this behavior one either might write a button code like this ... `<button type='button' ...` or one does actively suppress the triggering of the submit-default of such a button's click-event by calling `evt.preventDefault()` within this button's click-handler.

***Edit / Summary***

Having said all of the above I would change the OP's code towards this approach ...

*markup*

```
<button type="button" data-page="page1" class="posbutton">QB</button>

<tbody id="page1">
  {% for q in QBpage %}
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"></th>
      <td><h6>{{ q.player_name }}</h6></td>
      <td>
        <button
          type="button"
          data-player-name="{{ q.player_name }}"
          data-position="{{ q.position }}"
          class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm m-0 waves-effect"
        >Add</button>
      </td>
      <td><h6>{{ q.team }}</h6></td>
      <td><h6>{{ q.position }}</h6></td>
      <td><h6>{{ q.points }}</h6></td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

*script*

```
function showPage(pageId) {
  document
    .querySelectorAll('tbody')
    .forEach(tbody => tbody.style.display = 'none');
  document
    .querySelector(`#${ pageId }`)
    .style.display = 'table-row-group';
}
function updatePosition(name, position) {
  document
    .querySelector(`#${ position }_name`)
    .value = [name, position].join(' ');
}

function handleShowPage(evt) {
  showPage(evt.currentTarget.dataset.page);
}
function handleUpdatePosition(evt) {
  const { playerName, position } = evt.currentTarge.dataset;
  updatePosition(playerName, position);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document
    .querySelectorAll('button[data-page]')
    .forEach(button =>
      button.addEventListener('click', handleShowPage)
    );
  document
    .querySelectorAll('button[data-position][data-player-name]')
    .forEach(button =>
      button.addEventListener('click', handleUpdatePosition)
    );
});
```

Comment: Thanks again. A bit of working around and it works! But my myFunction isn't receiving anything now. A bit of tweaking will be needed, but it's 90% working now which is great.

Comment: @user14593966 ... btw ... *"... but it's 90% working now which is great. ..."* is nothing one just should accept. If there are errors, one can debug them.

Comment: Thanks again for all your useful advice. I'm a bit confused by your edit. I understand how to handle the showPage correctly now. Now it's just a matter of getting the myFunction to work again. I tried changing `<td><button> class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" onclick="myFunction('{{ player_data.player_name }} {{ player_data.position }}')">Add</button></td>` to `<button> type="button" class= etc etc..>` but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: It is because there are syntax errors with the `<td><button>...` code. In addition, I do not understand why one would concat two well distinct data values like `player_name` and `position` into one string value as the `myFunction`'s sole argument only to be forced to test it again via `txt.includes(...)`. Also be aware of to provide `type="button"` to every `<button/>` that is part of a `<form/>` and that is not supposed to trigger a `submit` event. And finally, within the button markup, shouldn't it be `q.player_name`/`q. position` instead of  `player_data.player_name`/`player_data.position`.

Comment: Syntax errors? I can't see where they would be. The buttons worked fine earlier. I've tried adding `type="button"` to all the buttons in `<td>` but still no change. You're correct about the `q.player_data.player_name/player_data.position`

Comment: The markup generating code states ... `<td><button> class="btn btn-outline-primary ...` which will not match the expected result ... have a look into my last ***Edit / Summary*** ... there it looks like that ... `<td><button type="button" ... class="..." >` which does generate syntactically correct/valid markup.

Comment: Thanks man! I learned a lot from your advice and examples shown here.